# VW vs percentage width for elements and scrollbar centering issues

Tags: html, css

I'm having a recurring issue with my site that when I use % to define widths, the scrollbar isn't accounted for so centering will be slightly off on pages that scroll and constant elements (like navigation menu) will jump a bit from page to page depending on if there's a bar or not. However if I use vw instead a horizontal scrollbar appears and it still doesn't fix the issue. Anyone know a workaround for this? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a working [repro] for debugging details. There is now ay to help you with a code snippet that shows your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help without seeing any code! I would generally avoid using % for widths unless it is to set it to 100%. There are better ways to make your pages dynamically re-size. that said, see below code:

```css
body {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* always Show vertical scrollbar */
}

div{
  background-color:skyblue;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h2>Show scrollbar</h2>
    <p>This example will always show the y scrollbar in a webpage to avoid the inconsistency of it only appearing on some pages.</p>
    <p>Do not put width: 100% on the body as it will cause the x scroll bar to appear.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```